# Diferença entre Pai.__init(self) e super(Pai, self).__init__()

Tags: python

Estou com um pouco de dúvidas sobre a questão da herança no `python`.

No seguinte teste, esperava que `quack` imprimisse o mesmo valor para as duas classes que criei:

```
class A(object):
    a,b = (None, None)
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'a'

    def quack(self):
        return 'retorno "%s" ' % self.a

class B(A):

    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        self.b = 'b'
```

Meu teste foi feito assim:

```
b = B()
a = A()

print(b.quack())
print(a.quack())
```

A saída foi:

```
retorno "None" 
retorno "a"
```

Porém eu pensava que os dois deveriam retornar a mesma coisa.

A herança da propriedade `a` só funcionou como eu esperava quando alterei o trecho do `super` para isso:

```
A.__init(self)
```

Retorno:

```
retorno "a"
retorno "a"
```

Tendo esses dois casos, qual é a diferença entre as duas declarações que criei?

Por que o super não utilizou o método da classe pai?

Comment: Sua saída não está trocada não? O retorno `None` é pra classe `B` e a `a` é pra classe `A`, certo?

Comment: É que meu print está invertido, vou postá-lo

Comment: @mgibsonbr percebi que quando mudei para `super(B, self)` deu certo. Acho que não entendi para que o super server :\

Comment: Haha não vi seu comentário, e acabei postando uma resposta dizendo exatamente isso... :P

Answer (score 3):

O problema é que o `super` não deve ser chamado na classe pai, e sim na própria classe:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.b = 'b'
```

Pois a ideia do `super` não é chamar o método numa classe específica (pra isso a segunda forma que você usou é a mais indicada), e sim chamar o método usando as mesmas regras de herança do python, apenas ignroando a classe atual:

```
class A(object): ...
class B(A): ...
class C(A): ...
class D(B, C): ...
class E(B): ...

class F(D, E):
    def __init__(self):
        super(F, self).__init__()
```

Esse exemplo acima vai tentar achar um método `__init__` em todas as classes da hierarquia, *exceto* o próprio `F`. E a ordem que ele vai buscar é definida pelo processo de herança (que lamentavelmente desconheço...). Isso valeria pra outro método qualquer também, tipo `super(F, self).foo()`.

```
class F(D, E):
    def __init__(self):
        super(E, self).__init__()
```

Se você usasse esse código, por outro lado, o Python só iria buscar um `__init__` nas superclasses de `E`, ou seja, `B` e depois `A`. Mesmo que `C` tenha um `__init__`, e `C` seja uma das superclasses de `F`, ele não seria buscado nesse caso. E em particular, o próprio `E` não é buscado (pois o `super` assume que é pra ignorar `E`, da mesma forma como ele ignorou `F` no exemplo anterior).

Comment: P.S. Tenho certeza que aqui mesmo no SOpt tem uma pergunta explicando a ordem de busca dos métodos na presença de herança múltipla, mas não estou conseguindo encontrar pra deixar de referência.

Comment: Só pra complementar: Python não obriga que a escrita dos parâmetros de métodos de classes herdadas da mesma forma como no PHP? Quero dizer, se o método `__init__` tem os parâmetros a e b na classe `A`, ele nao será obrigatório na classe B(A)?

Comment: Não, aliás eu nem sabia que em PHP era assim... Não conheço nenhuma outra linguagem que obrigue isso, aliás. Em Java, por exemplo, as subclasses podem ter os métodos - e construtores - que quiserem, a única coisa obrigatória é que cada construtor chame um construtor da subclasse implícita ou explicitamente de maneira válida. Python nem isso. E quanto aos demais métodos, se tiver os mesmos parâmetros é override, senão é overload (em Java, em Python tudo é override, já que Python não é estaticamente tipado).

Comment: A consequência é que em Python é fácil herdar de uma classe mas tornar a classe filha incompatível com a classe mãe... Se o programador quer herdar respeitando o [Princípio da Substituição de Liskov](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_substitui%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Liskov) - ou os demais princípios do [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) - isso é por conta dele, a linguagem em si não impõe isso. P.S. no comentário anterior eu quis dizer "chame um construtor da **super**classe", não "sub".